# How to use multithreading inside an JPA camel route

Tags: apache-camel

We have an importer running on a powerful, multi-core server. However, our Apache Camel routes are single threaded, which is a shame.

Our [camel] importer is a single-instance program. How can I make a specific route process the messages using multiple threads? The messages are atomic and are processed by a bean, which already does this in a thread-safe way.
I am already happy if I could process batches (maxMessagesPerPoll) in threads and have idle time until the next poll takes place (after all, that's still better than sequential processing).

Here is one of the routes I would like to make multithreaded:

```
public void onConfigure() throws Exception {
    // This is a JPA query which selects all unprocessed modules
    String query = RouteQueryHelper.selectNextUnprocessedStaged(ImportAction.IMPORT_MODULES);

    from("jpa:com.so.importer.entity.ModuleStageEntity" +
            "?consumer.query=" + query +
            "&maxMessagesPerPoll=2000" +
            "&consumeLockEntity=false" +
            "&consumer.delay=1000" +
            "&consumeDelete=false")

        .transacted().policy("CAMEL_DEFAULT_POLICY")

        .bean(moduleImportService) // processes the entity and updates it's status flag
        .to("log:import-module?groupInterval=10000")

        .routeId("so.route.import-module");
}
```

The route has `consumeDelete=false`, because we use a status property on the entity instead (which is modified and saved). The status property is also respected in the `consumer.query`.

We use camel version 2.17.1 in spring boot (1.3.8.RELEASE) on Java 8.

EDIT 2019-Jan-21: The entities have a method with @Consumed on them, which pushes the entity into the next route after it was processed:

```
@Consumed
public void gotoNextStatus() {
    switch (stageStatus) {
        case STAGED: setStageStatus(StageStatus.IMPORTED); break;
        case IMPORTED: setStageStatus(StageStatus.RENDERED); break;
        case RENDERED: setStageStatus(StageStatus.DONE); break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could introduce some asynchronisation by sending your messages to an intermediate [SEDA](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html) endpoint:

```
from("jpa:")
...
.to("seda:intermediateStage")
```

And then put the real processing inside a new route with N concurrrent SEDA consumers (default is one):

```
from("seda:intermediateStage?concurrentConsumers=5")
.process(...)
```

Comment: JPA uses polling: wouldn't this pattern result in entities being pushed to the seda route multiple times, if they are processing slower than the jpa is pulling? It works in a single-route pattern, because the next poll is done when the entity status field is updated and does not match the query anymore. I guess it would require to introduce a new status for "is ready for processing in seda"?

Comment: My assumtion is wrong, it would not push multiple times to the seda route, but the next route (which listens on the status fields next value) would trigger before the entity is actually processed by the seda route.

Comment: This solution _might_ work, but it requires some serious because of transactional issues. One is that lazy jpa entities do not like to be passed to other threads.
I am sorry, but I am unable to verify this answer as the work to figure things out is most likely higher than rewriting the apache camel code into a spring batch importer application.

Comment: @dube: If you can't verify the answer, why did you accept it?

Comment: @Kukeltje you expect me to understand my reasoning of 2 years ago? :) Probably because it seems to be correct (other places mention the same, once you know what to look for), but the whole environment annoyed us so much that we replaced it with spring batch. Never looked back